# Screen lock not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 22.04, lock-screen, bug-reporting

Screen lock is not working in my Ubuntu 22.04. I can see below logs:

```
Aug 15 12:39:12 navratan-ubuntu gnome-shell[2791]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Aug 15 12:39:37 navratan-ubuntu gsd-media-keys[3070]: Couldn't lock screen: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dio_2derror_2dquark.Code24: Timeout was reached
```

My screen privacy settings are as below:

> Blank Screen Delay = 10 minutes

> Automatic Screen lock = true

> Automatic Screen Lock Delay = 30 Seconds

> Lock screen on suspend = true

> Show notification on lock screen = true

Please help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you didn't resolve yet, I suggest you to try in this way:

First try `xdg-screensaver lock` on the terminal. If it doesn't work and the pc doesn't lock then try:

```
 gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

It should return `true`

After that you have to type:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

This will be permit to your device to lock again. I had the same issue, and it worked for me.

Comment: Good to know, although in my case, `disable-lock-screen` is set to `false` but screen lock still does not work anymore.

Comment: Specific for Ubuntu Budgie, see https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/lock-screen-no-longer-works-after-22-04-upgrade/6194

Comment: Thank you very much! It said that it was false before, but I ran the last command just in case and that fixed it