# Cannot lock screen on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 22.04, lock-screen

I have seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423645/screen-lock-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04)

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

returns `false` for me

I am using gdm3 not lightdm

Issues:

win+L does not lock screen

Lid close does not lock screen

Comment: Thanks for posting. I have the same problem after updating to 22.04